# Issue with MediaPlayer can not play all audio files

Tags: android, debugging, android-mediaplayer

I've a problem with the MediaPlayer .
i've built an application composed of 4 activities , in each activity i have a listView of items and once i click on an item it plays a mediafile .
Well , it works fine until after playing some audio files it can not play anymore .
I've this errors in the Run log .

```
D/ViewRootImpl@1250751[ColorsActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@1250751[ColorsActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
                   JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
V/MediaPlayer: constructor
V/MediaPlayer: setListener
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setParameter: key 1400
V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: set_session_id(): 23689
V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(23689)
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setDataSourceFD: fd 83
V/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(83, 2623336, 80742)
V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
V/MediaPlayer: prepare
V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=200, ext1=10973, ext2=0
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (10973, 0)
V/MediaPlayer: callback application
V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
               prepared
               signal application thread
               callback application
               back from callback
V/MediaPlayer: prepare complete - status=0
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
V/MediaPlayer: invoke 68
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
V/MediaPlayer: start
V/MediaPlayer: invoke 68
V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-19
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
V/MediaPlayer: callback application
               back from callback
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
```

Here is the code of one of my activities :

```
public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer media;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
        //create an array of strings
        final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.one), "lutti", R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.number_one));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.two), "otiiko", R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.number_two));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.three), "tolookosu", R.drawable.number_three, R.raw.number_three));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.four), "oyyisa", R.drawable.number_four, R.raw.number_four));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.five), "massokka", R.drawable.number_five, R.raw.number_five));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.six), "temmokka", R.drawable.number_six, R.raw.number_six));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.seven), "kenekaku", R.drawable.number_seven, R.raw.number_seven));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.eight), "kawinta", R.drawable.number_eight, R.raw.number_eight));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.nine), "wo’e", R.drawable.number_nine, R.raw.number_nine));
        words.add(new Word(getString(R.string.ten), "na’aacha", R.drawable.number_ten, R.raw.number_ten));

        for (int k = 0; k < words.size(); k++) {
            Log.i("NumbersActivity", "At index " + k + "we have : " + words.get(k));
        }
        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words, R.color.category_numbers);
        ;

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();
                MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this, words.get(position).getmSongId());
                media.start();
            }
        });
    }
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
        if (media != null) {
            // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
            // because we no longer need it.
            media.release();

            // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
            // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
            // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
            media = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
}
```

Comment: -19 is a problem with accessing a port (see [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h)). Are you cleaning up resources properly? This isn't really enough to tell you what you are doing wrong. You should supply a minimal code example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Davei just edited my question so you can see the code of one of the four activities !! Thank you!!

Comment: How long are the audio files you are playing?

Comment: each one at maximum 4 seconds.

Comment: In that case, take a look at [`SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool). It might suit your use case better. `MediaPlayer` can be slow to clean up resources on the native side (it's not as synchronous as you might hope). My guess would be that after clicking a few times you simply overwhelm the device capabilities.

Comment: @Dave First thank you for your help ans support !!

Comment: Then , i don't know where is the problem in another version of the app (made by someone else) it works fine !!

Comment: Another alternative is to create only one `MediaPlayer`. Only release it in the `onDestroy` callback of the `Acitivity`. In the click listener, call `reset`, `setDataSource`, and `prepare` rather than using the static `create` method to create a new instance.

Comment: @Dave okaaay i'll test that asap ! i still have one question , why this small application can cause this error :I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: That happens pretty often, especially on app startup. Nothing to worry about.